# Apache Camel RSS Feed Processor skips with feeds of same pubdate

Tags: rss, apache-camel

I have a camel setup to read feeds, I use splitEntries=true and I use available org.apache.camel.component.rss.RssEndpoint , but it skips the feeds with same timestamp. Does anybody know what is happening?

Comment: Look in the source code to see what goes on

Comment: Here is the update of my findings. when we use splitEntries=true , by default it uses updatedDateFilter for filtering the feeds, when I see the org.apache.camel.component.atom.UpdatedDateFilter code, it actually skips the date like lastUpdate.after(updated) || lastUpdate.equals(updated) . So all other feeds with same timestamps are getting skipped. I should use own filter extending the updatedDateFilter, so let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution for it, need to customize the FeedPollingConsumer class which internally uses the UpdatedDateFilter, and remove the

```
lastUpdate.after(updated) || lastUpdate.equals(updated)
```

And Remove the lastUpdate.equals(updated) , to process the same pubDate timestamp feeds. UpdatedDateFilter is not extensible , too so checkout implementing your own from the FeedFilter interface.

Thanks. Let me know if you have any better solution.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. I have logged a ticket to get this fixed - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6436. We love contributions, so patches is much welcome.

Comment: Sure Claus thanks for the update, Will work on the patch and let you know soon